Is this the correct site to ask about US tax data?
I'm trying to find out some information on the number of people in the various tax brackets in the US.   I'm not sure if that type of question is correct for this site, can someone let me know please?
If it's not, does anyone know where I could ask it or find out that information?
Thank you

Demographic information like that is definitely not quantitative finance. We're more concerned with issues like asset valuation, risk management, and market microstructure.

Thank you for your help
